# new to android - supporting Supporting Multiple Screens

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a galaxy Note 2, which I think is considered a large screen. When I run my app, I want it to use the activity_main.xml file in the layout-large folder. But it does not. It used the activity_main.xml in the layout folder.

Here is what i have tried:

I create a folder called layout-large under the res directory. so the tree looks like this:

res

```
layout--> activity_main.xml

layout-large--> activity_main.xml
```

I tried to go through the documentation, I didn't find anything.
I also placed this code in the manefest:

```
  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


<supports-screens 
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"

    />
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem could be solved by using new qualifiers as defined in Android Docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers).

Comment: ok. try using the new qualifiers. see this link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers

Comment: Galaxy Note 2 has a normal screen, not xlarge; using the new qualifiers is the solution, and should be edited in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your target SDK is 13 and above you may want to be looking at the tablet qualifiers:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml          # sub 480dp handsets
res/layout-sw480dp/main_activity.xml  # large 480dp handsets and phabets
res/layout-sw600dp/main_actiivty.xml  # 7" tablets like nexus 7
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml  # 10" tablets
```